# Unhiding relevant data in an Each Loop on a button click of dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a table that's populated from Node with each row representing a document. There's too much repetitive data, so I want some of it to be hidden and then unhidden on a button click.

In the For Each loop in my pug template I've added an icon so that when you click it, the hidden contents should be shown.

```
tbody
    each output in project.outputs
         tr
           td= output.title
              svg.report__icon.dropbtn
                 table.dropdown-content
                    - for (let i=0; i<5; i++)
                       output.repetitive-data[i]
```

I then wrote an onclick event in js, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            document.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show')
        })
    })
```

However while this does allow a click on each icon, no matter which icon/row is clicked it only ever unhides the data in the first row of the table, which does make sense, because 'querySelector' is going to toggle the first element it finds that has that class.

How would I toggle the correct CSS show/hide property for the correct row/element? Do I need a loop within a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` also works when called on regular DOM elements, in that case it will limit its search within that element only

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle('show')
    })
})
```